# JDBC error when connectingto remote database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created a remote database [in this website](https://www.000webhost.co)

[image]

and then I created a table

[image]

After that, I try this Java code to connect to my remote DB:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
try{  
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://www.000webhost.com/id1538634_mydrive","root","id1538634_root");
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into membre(name,pseudo,pw,profilephoto) values(?,?,?,?)");
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
   ps.setString(1, t1.getText());
   ps.setString(2, t2.getText());
   ps.setString(3,  pw);
   ps.setBinaryStream(4,   (InputStream)is, (int)( new File(s).length() ));
   ps.executeUpdate();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration with success"); 
}catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When compiling, I don't get anything. No exception and no error and no data is inserted.

Comment: Are you sure a stack trace is not printed?

Comment: Why would you expect data to be inserting by *compiling* the code? Nothing happens until you *run* the code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry what do you mean by stack trace

Comment: @Andreas i want to connect to  this remote database and insert data. yeaah nothinghappens coz i wonder if  my code to connect to the database  is wring

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: the question is: is your code being executed at all?

Comment: no dialog is shown and no error in console. I wonder am using a wrong structure to connect ot the database

Comment: Your database is opened only for `localhost` and not for `jdbc:mysql://000webhost.com:3306` (MySQL on port 3306 is default). Nowadays the `Class.forName` part nolonger is needed.

Comment: @JoopEggen  please can you explain  more . Dyou meanthat ihave tochange Class.forName

Comment: No, just that it no longer is necessary. The error probably is that your MySQL is not accessible from the internet; by default MySQL runs on `localhost:3306` (local machine, port 3306). For the internet one needs a MySQL user for your domain, and allow port 3306 through the firewall. Better run a java web application or such on the server, that accesses the database through localhost. Safer.

Comment: Just for your info - above code is working with local database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the following change to your `my.cnf` file

```
`my.cnf`

bind-address = www.000webhost.com (OR)
bind-address = xx.xx.xx.xx (IP Address)
```

And if you don't have any user login issues, you should be able to connect to the MySQL Database from your Java code.